# How can I redirect a page to itself?

Tags: php, routes

Here is my website's folder structure:

```
myweb/
    index.php
    files/
        autoloader.php
        login.php
```

And here is my script:

```
// login.php

class login{

    public function __construct () {
        function signed(){
            header('Location: ../');
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function index(){

        echo isset($_SESSION['error_message']) ? $_SESSION['error_message'] : null;

        if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
            signed();
        }

        $_SESSION['login'] = 1;

        if ( $_SESSION['login'] == 1 ) {
            $_SESSION['error_message'] = 'something is wrong';
            header('location: ../login?arg=value');
        }
    }
}
```

When I load this path:

```
localhost/myweb/login
```

Here is two cases:

1. `$_SESSION['login']` is equal to `1`: My script redirects me to this path: `localhost/myweb`
2. `$_SESSION['login']` isn't equal to `1`: My script redirects me to this path: `localhost`
   The first case is fine, I mean it works as expected. But the second case is wrong, I mean it doesn't work as expected. In the second case, it should redirect me to this path: `localhost/myweb/login?arg=value`, not `localhost`. Well how can I fix it?

**Note:** All pages pass through the index.php. Also `index()` function is by default and no need to mention it in the url.

---

I have a solution: I can use:

```
header("Refresh:0");
```

Instead of:

```
header('location: ../login?arg=value');
```

But there is just a small problem: **Passing Parameters**. So how can I use both `header("Refresh:0");` and `?arg=value` together?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
header("Location: ".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
```

---

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: There is no `QUERY_STRING`, I want to add it now. So `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is always empty in this case.

Comment: Use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?".` and the query string after

Comment: Thank you .. upvote. I will try it and let you know it worked or not.